# LaTeX does not recognize some references from bib-file

Tags: biblatex, biber

I am using TeXstudio and Citavi as a citation manager for my references. Everything worked fine, but now when I update my library, LaTeX does not seem to pick up the added references. 
All references appear in the `bib` file but the new ones do not appear in the `bbl` file.

The errors I get are the following:

```
Undefined control sequence.
Undefined control sequence.
'babel/polyglossia' detected but 'csquotes' missing.
Citation 'Pee.2017' on page 2 undefined
Citation 'Giannousakis.2017' on page 3 undefined
Overfull \hbox (22.68143pt too wide) in paragraph
There were undefined references.
Please (re)run Biber on the file:(biblatex) Exposeé(biblatex) and rerun LaTeX afterwards.
```

Regarding `csquotes`: it is not pre-installed in TeXstudio and I am not sure how to integrate new packages.

Comment: The `Undefined control sequence.` errors are serious and should be resolved. The errors you report here are shortened versions of the full error message, which should include information about *which* command is undefined. If you are using an editor you may have to click on the message to be sent to the relevant part of your document or see the full message. The message also asks you to re(run) Biber, did you run Biber? If so, did Biber report any errors or warnings?

Comment: Please note that TeXstudio is just an editor. It is just the piece of software you use to write your `.tex` files. As such TeXstudio does not have any LaTeX packages pre-installed and does not handle the installation of packages. Packages are installed and updated through a so-called *TeX distribution*. You must have a TeX distribution installed on your machine to be able to run LaTeX to compile your `.tex` file into a PDF. The most popular distributions are TeX live (for almost all operating systems, Mac TeX for mac OS) and MikTeX (mainly for Windows, but recently also for some Linux systems)

Comment: Any news here? Unfortunately, the error messages are missing crucial information, so it is hard to give a definitive answer without guessing. Ideally you would try to add an example document (a so-called MWE https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864 or MWEB https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864) to your question that reproduces the issue at hand. Without that information we can't really say anything and your question is unclear. If the question remains unclear and open for too long I will vote to close it.

Comment: Any news here? As mentioned before this question is unanswerable in its current form. I will vote to close as unclear if it is not edited soon.

Comment: I voted to close this question as *unclear what you are asking* because it is missing crucial information about the errors and requests for more details were not followed up on. I will happily vote to reopen the question if it is edited with more information.